# How to let oozie access S3 to get the workflow.xml and ***.jar

Tags: amazon-s3, oozie

I want to trigger a oozie job by：

`oozie job -oozie http://***.***.***.***:11000/oozie -config /tmp/test1/job.properties -run`

My job.properties:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=s3a://my-bucket/job1
user.name=hdfs
jobTracker=cm001:8032
nameNode=hdfs://cm001:8020
mainClass=****
```

My ***.jar and workflow.xml is all located in `s3a://my-bucket/job1`, I know i have to config the S3 endpoint and the AK/SK to let oozie access S3, but where can i config these configuration? How to config this configuration? I didn't find any document in oozie official document.

Answer (score 1):

My scenario is use Cloudera to manage Oozie and HDFS. And i want let Oozie to use Ceph as the filesystem. My configuration is:

1. Add S3 related configuration to `oozie-site.xml` in oozie server and `core-site.xml` in HDFS.

Add following configuration:

```
    fs.s3a.impl=org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
    fs.s3a.path.style.access=true
    fs.s3a.endpoint=***
    fs.s3a.access.key=***
    fs.s3a.secret.key=***
```

2. The path of workflow.xml shouldn't located in root folder.

   Good example: `'s3a://bucket/test/'`
   Bad example: `'sa3://bucket'`